# Instantiating modules in SystemVerilog

Tags: hdl, adder, system-verilog, module

This is a picture of a system that I am building:

[image: block diagram]

([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrVS5.jpg))

I am writing SystemVerilog for the Counter4to3 module, whilst the other modules (Full adder and half adder) have already been provided to me.

So far for the Counter4to3 module I have:

```
module Counter4to3(input logic a3, a2, a1, a0,
  output logic y2, y1, y0);
  FullAdder(a3,a2,a1, , );
  HalfAdder( ,a0, ,y0);
  HalfAdder();
endmodule
```

I am having difficulty determining some of the inputs and outputs for the full adder and half adder modules. For instance, one of the full adder modules is actually an input to one of the half adders, and because of this, I am not sure what its output should be as it is not exactly one of either a3,a2,a1,a0,y2,y1, or y0.

I appreciate any help, 
thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry. As one of the full adder outputs is connected to an input, would the route be to make a "temporary variable", and have this variable connect to the corresponding input of the half adder module?

Answer (score 1):

Every connection in your diagram needs to have a unique name. Therefore, you need to make up names for the wires that don't already have any.

Answer (score 1):

The most worrying is that you talk of a *"temporary variable"* which tells me you are still thinking using standard programming language terms.

When dealing with HDL you should start thinking in terms of **hardware**. In HDL it is common to call that a 'connection' just as a wires is used to connect two chips.

If you think in those terms you will see that this:

```
FullAdder(a3,a2,a1, , );  
//                 ^ ^  Unconnected outputs!
```

is a piece of hardware with two unconnected outputs. Which is fine.

But this:

```
HalfAdder( ,a0, ,y0);
//        ^   Unconnected input!
```

is a piece of hardware with an unconnected input. That is a big NO=NO!

I would compare it to NOT plugging in your headphones and still expect to have sound.

So yes, you should connect all inputs to something. Even if you only to tie them low (0) or high (1).